# Add 30 seonds to minutes in time class in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, activesupport

I used the following format in Ruby which is working fine.

```
Time.new.strftime("%a %d %b, %Y %H:%M") # output "Thu 05 Aug, 2021 12:29"
```

But I need to add additional 30 seconds to the current time. I tried with active support, but unable to figure out how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _"I need to add additional 30 seconds to the minutes"_ – what do you mean exactly? Do you want to _add_ 30 seconds to the existing time instance? Do you want to _set_ the seconds of the time instance to 30 regardless of their actual value? Do you just want append `:30` to the output string? Maybe something else? Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry for the misconception. I need to add 30 seconds to current time.updated the description

Comment: It's a little confusing that you didn't include the seconds in your output although the question is all about seconds :-)

Comment: *" I tried with active support, but unable to figure out how to do it."* -- I'd be curious to know what you tried! Given the solution is basically to write `+ 30.seconds`, I don't see much scope for going wrong here. Maybe you were trying to "add 30 seconds" **after** converting a `Time` object into a `String`?!

Comment: If you just need to add 30 seconds to the current time this would also work: `30.seconds.from_now.strftime("%a %d %b, %Y %H:%M")`

Answer (score 1):

Given an instance of time: (Rails flavored)

```
t = Time.current
#=> Thu, 05 Aug 2021 10:55:12 CEST +02:00
```

There are several ways to add 30 seconds to it, e.g.

- Ruby's [`Time#+`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html#2B-method) with an integer:

  ```
   t + 30
   #=> Thu, 05 Aug 2021 10:55:42 CEST +02:00
  ```
- Ruby's [`Time#+`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Time.html#2B-method) with a Rails' [`ActiveSupport::Duration`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html) instance from [`Numeric#seconds`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Numeric.html#method-i-seconds):

  ```
   t + 30.seconds
   #=> Thu, 05 Aug 2021 10:55:42 CEST +02:00
  ```
- Rails' [`Time#advance`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-i-advance) which takes a hash:

  ```
   t.advance(seconds: 30)
   #=> Thu, 05 Aug 2021 10:55:42 CEST +02:00
  ```

Answer (score 0):

%S - Second of the minute (00..59)

```rb
Time.new.strftime("%a %d %b, %Y %H:%M:%S")
# "Thu 05 Aug, 2021 10:18:50"
```

+ 30 seconds

```rb
(Time.new + 30.seconds).strftime("%a %d %b, %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Or 0.5 min (30 sec)

```rb
(Time.new + 0.5.minutes).strftime("%a %d %b, %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: @Stefan agree with you - question is ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

There is a method `since` for time object which can be used for this purpose

`Time.new.since(30.seconds).strftime("%a %d %b, %Y %H:%M:%S")`